# Search results is not preserved after going back from details page

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have created a site which have the issue regarding filtered and pagination base records.The searching for first time worked properly but when I am going to detail view of item and then when back to the list view of items  I am getting the whole list of Items instead of my searched items. I have taken the searched keywords in session but that is not working for me.

```
if (count($_POST) > 0 && count($this->session->userdata('post_data'))==0 || $this->uri->segment(4) == true && count($this->session->userdata('post_data')) == 0) {
    $this->session->set_userdata('post_data', $_POST);
    $this->session->set_userdata('previous_post_data', $_POST);
    redirect('package/packages_list/');
} else if(count($_POST) == 0 && count($this->session->userdata('post_data'))==0){
    $this->session->set_userdata('post_data', $this->session->userdata('previous_post_data'));
    redirect('package/packages_list/' . $this->uri->segment(3));}
else if ($this->session->userdata('post_data')) {
    $_POST = $this->session->userdata('post_data');
```